# Android App: Proximity

Tags: android, iphone, windows

Is there an API for Android that will find other people nearby running the same app? For instance, if you were to perform a "scan" it tries to find other people running the same app nearby. Would it be possible to perform the same task across multiple OS (`Android, iPhone, Windows, etc.`)?

Or would the best way be to just have the app communicate to a server your location and have a server-side app that pushes a list of others nearby???

My goal is to find an easy way to eventually transmit data between two devices contigent on those that are nearby.

Comment: FYI, Windows Proximity "browsing" for nearby peers does not currently interop with Android/iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that the second option is the best. The other route to go might be to look into the Android's [Bluetooth API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/package-summary.html) as continually updating your location with a remote server is costly from a battery standpoint.